# Angularjs does not magically create input element for editing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to edit an element in real time by triggering a function on ng-click with AngularJS.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="row question">{{questions.1.name}} <a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ng-click="editQuestion(questions.1.name)"></a></div>
```

And the js:

```
function QuestionsMap($scope) {
$scope.questions = {
"1": {
  "name": "Hello! Do you like to travel?",
  "ID": "1",
  "answer": {
    "yes": {
      "name": "Yes",
    },
    "no": {
      "name": "No",
    }
  }
}

};
$scope.editQuestion = function (name) {
  $scope.editing = $scope.questions[name];
};
}
```

What am I missing? Is the editQuestion function not properly written?

Comment: What happens when the ng-click triggers now?

Comment: What value are you trying to store inside of $scope.editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input field wont show up magically you have to code that.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newquestion"><input type="button" ng-click="add()" value="save">
```

controller, you can specify what you want to push inside like `$scope.questions.push({'name':$scope.newquestion.name,'id':$scope.newquestion.id});`

```
$scope.add = function(){
    $scope.questions.push($scope.newquestion);
    $scope.newquestion = "";    
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`$scope.questions[name]` isn't anything. There is no `$scope.questions["Hello, do you like to travel"]`. There is however a `$scope.questions["1"]`. Try passing in `questions.1.ID` instead of `questions.1.name`

---

Also @c-smile is right. Don't start your keys with integers. That is not allowed in js. For this to work you need to switch to something like `'n1'`

Comment: I've updated the html to ng-click="editQuestion(questions.n1.ID)", renamed to n1, and rewritten the function to 

$scope.editQuestion = function (name) {
    $scope.editing = $scope.questions["n1"];
};

And still nothing :S

Answer (score 1):

This `questions.1.name` is incorrect syntax from JS perspective. Name of the variable in JS cannot start from digit. So you shall refactor your code to  something like this:

```
<div class="row question">{{questions.n1.name}}
```

and so

```
"n1": { ... }
```